# Sampling from a sum of two distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, sampling, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose I have two cumulative probability density functions $F$ and $G$. It is well known that I can sample from $F$ using $F^{-1}(X)$, where $X$ is uniformly distributed.

Now let $H = hF + (1-h)G$ for some $h \in [0, 1]$. Intuitively, I feel that I should be able to sample from $H$ using the following function:

$$
U^{-1}(X) = 
\begin{cases}
F^{-1}(X/h), & X < h, \\
G^{-1}((X-h)/(1-h)), & X > h.
\end{cases}
$$

In effect, we use the uniform random variable first to choose between $F$ and $G$, and then to sample from it. Is my thinking correct, or are there some caveats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct! Here is the proof (I assume $h\in (0,1)$):

Let $U\sim Unif[0,1]$ and sample according to

$$
Y = \begin{cases}
F^{-1}\left(U\over h\right), & U \leq h, \\
G^{-1}\left({U-h\over 1-h }\right), & U > h
\end{cases}.
$$
Then

$$\begin{align}P(Y\leq y)&=P(Y\leq y,U\leq h)+P(Y\leq y,U> h)\\
&=P\left(F^{-1}\left(U\over h\right)\leq y,U\leq h\right)+P\left(G^{-1}\left({U-h\over 1-h }\right)\leq y,U>h\right)\\
&=P\left(U\leq hF(y),U\leq h\right)+P\left(U\leq h+(1-h)G(y),U>h\right)\\
&=P\left(U\leq \min\{hF(y),h\}\right)+P\left(h<U\leq h+(1-h)G(y)\right)\\
&=P\left(U\leq hF(y)\right)+P\left(h<U\leq h+(1-h)G(y)\right)\\
&=hF(y)+(1-h)G(y)
\end{align}$$

as desired.

---

Here is an alternative approach: Let $U_1,U_2\sim Unif[0,1]$ be independent and sample according to

$$
Y = \begin{cases}
F^{-1}(U_2), & U_1 \leq h, \\
G^{-1}(U_2), & U_1 > h
\end{cases}.
$$

Then

$$\begin{align}P(Y\leq y)&=P(U_1\leq h)P(Y\leq y|U_1\leq h)+P(U_1> h)P(Y\leq y|U_1> h)\\
&=hP(F^{-1}(U_2)\leq y)+(1-h)P(G^{-1}(U_2)\leq y)\\
&=hP(U_2\leq F(y))+(1-h)P(U_2\leq G(y))\\
&=hF(y)+(1-h)G(y)\\
\end{align}$$

as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and derivation of the CDF. But I fail to see why $U_1$ and $U_2$ must be independent. Which part of the analysis fails if $U_2 = U_1 / h$ for $x < h$ and $U_2 = (U_1 - h) / (1 - h)$ for $x > h$?

Comment: @akvilas You are right-my apologies! I have updated my response to reflect your approach.